# How to find devices on my VPN network?

Tags: networking, vpn, cisco-anyconnect

I have successfully connected to my workplace's vpn network with `openconnect`.  I have confirmed that I am connected because I can view intranet websites.  Now I'm trying to my work machine using ssh.  I know it's still on and I know it's running sshd.  But using it's hostname gives a DNS resolution error.  `nmap` also isn't listing any other devices on my network.  How do I find or at least list ip addresses on the VPN network?

my scan attempt:

```bsh
$ ip addr
-- snip --
12: vpn0: <POINTOPOINT,MULTICAST,NOARP,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1406 qdisc fq_codel state UNKNOWN group default qlen 500
    link/none 
    inet 192.168.254.65/32 scope global vpn0
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 fe80::6025:18b4:70c:57b2/64 scope link stable-privacy 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
$ nmap -sT 192.168.254.*
Starting Nmap 7.80 ( https://nmap.org ) at 2020-03-17 23:00 CDT
Nmap scan report for 192.168.254.65
Host is up (0.00013s latency).
Not shown: 998 closed ports
PORT     STATE SERVICE
4000/tcp open  remoteanything
6667/tcp open  irc

Nmap done: 256 IP addresses (1 host up) scanned in 5.84 seconds
```

nmap only shows my home desktop running bitlbee and nomachine.  Where is my work desktop?  Where are all the other computers on the network?

Answer (score 0):

The issue is you are scanning your network scope on the VPN address network pool. When the VPN server gives connecting clients addresses (in your case 192.168.254.65), it is giving out IPs on a different network that the segment that your on site work machines are on. When you are scanning, you are only scanning other people that may be on the VPN too and not your work network. As a security measure, scanning for other clients on this network is most likely blocked. Your best bet is to first try and ping your on-premise work machine with its full qualified domain name, ex mycomputer.domain.local. If that does not work, then your VPN client does not grab a DNS server from the server when connecting to allow you to resolve hostnames natively. This can be fixed by editing the DNS entry for the vpn0 interface and adding your works on site DNS server address.

Another issue as that between the two networks VPN network and work network, there may not be a firewall rule allowing ssh traffic. There is a lot of possible issues and your best bet is to ask the person who setup the VPN/runs the firewall to check/add a rule for you.